Unable To Get Row Data When Datagrid(SfDataGrid) Is Grouped
I'm not receiving accurate row data when I try to retrieve it while the column is grouped. For instance, it gives me the second row data while I try to receive the first row data. The reason for this is that the data source's row list and the data grid list length don't match since the data grid contains extra group header rows.
How can I solve this?
Reproduce The Problem.
1.import Sfdatagrid package first.
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: JobHistoryPage(),
    );
  }
}

class JobHistoryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Dummy job history list
    List<JobHistory> dummyJobHistoryList = List.generate(
      20,
      (index) => JobHistory(
        jobOrderNo: "Job_$index",
        fpoNo: "FPO_$index",
        item: "ItemAbcdEfg_$index",
        creationDate: "2024-12-19",
        planStartDate: "2024-12-20",
        planCmplDate: "2024-12-25",
        fpoQty: index * 100,
        goodQty: index * 90,
        badQty: index * 10,
        trnQty: index * 80,
        rackQty: index * 70,
        madeP: (index % 100).toDouble(),
        dueMadeP: (100 - index % 100).toDouble(),
        customerName: "Customer_$index",
        customerPo: "PO_$index",
        buyerName: "Buyer_$index",
      ),
    );

    final jobHistoryDataSource = JobHistoryDataSource(
      jobHistoryData: dummyJobHistoryList,
    );
    jobHistoryDataSource.addColumnGroup(
        ColumnGroup(name: "Job Order No", sortGroupRows: false));

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Job History Table"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
              child: JobDetailsTableWidget(
                source: jobHistoryDataSource,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class JobDetailsTableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const JobDetailsTableWidget({super.key, required this.source});

  final JobHistoryDataSource source;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfDataGrid(
      rowHeight: 32,
      headerRowHeight: 38,
      source: source,
      allowExpandCollapseGroup: true,
      // autoExpandGroups: false,
      columnWidthCalculationRange: ColumnWidthCalculationRange.allRows,
      frozenColumnsCount: 2,
      groupCaptionTitleFormat: '{Key} - {ItemsCount}',
      gridLinesVisibility: GridLinesVisibility.both,
      headerGridLinesVisibility: GridLinesVisibility.none,
      columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.auto,
      shrinkWrapRows: true,
      columns: <GridColumn>[
        ...source.rows.first.getCells().map(
              (cell) => GridColumn(
                visible: !["Job Order No"].contains(cell.columnName),
                columnName: cell.columnName,
                label: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    cell.columnName,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
      ],
      onCellTap: (details) {
        if (details.rowColumnIndex.columnIndex == 2) {
          log(source._jobHisRowData[details.rowColumnIndex.rowIndex - 1]
              .getCells()
              .elementAt(2)
              .value);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class JobHistoryDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  /// Creates the employee data source class with required details.
  JobHistoryDataSource({required List<JobHistory> jobHistoryData}) {
    _jobHisData = jobHistoryData;
    _jobHisRowData = jobHistoryData.map<DataGridRow>((e) {
      Map<String, dynamic> map = e.toMapForTab();
      return DataGridRow(
        cells: [
          ...List.generate(
            map.length,
            (index) {
              return DataGridCell(
                columnName: map.entries.elementAt(index).key,
                value: map.entries.elementAt(index).value,
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  List<DataGridRow> _jobHisRowData = [];
  List<JobHistory> _jobHisData = [];
  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => _jobHisRowData;
  List<JobHistory> get jobHisData => _jobHisData;
  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    final int rowIndex = effectiveRows.indexOf(row);

    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((e) {
      LinearGradient? getColor() {
        if (e.columnName == 'Made P %') {
          try {
            Color fillColor = Colors.green;
            double fillPercent = double.parse(e.value
                .toString()
                .replaceAll('%', '')); // fills for container from side
            if (fillPercent <= 10) {
              fillColor = Colors.red; // 0-10
            } else if (fillPercent <= 20) {
              fillColor = Colors.deepOrange; // 10-20
            } else if (fillPercent <= 30) {
              fillColor = Colors.orange; // 20-30
            } else if (fillPercent <= 40) {
              fillColor = Colors.amber; // 30-40
            } else if (fillPercent <= 50) {
              fillColor = Colors.yellow; // 40-50
            } else if (fillPercent <= 60) {
              fillColor = Colors.teal; // 50-60
            } else if (fillPercent <= 70) {
              fillColor = Colors.cyan; // 60-70
            } else if (fillPercent <= 80) {
              fillColor = Colors.blue; // 70-80
            } else if (fillPercent <= 90) {
              fillColor = Colors.indigo; // 80-90
            } else if (fillPercent < 100) {
              fillColor = Colors.purple; // 90-99
            } else {
              fillColor = Colors.green; // 100
            }
            fillPercent = fillPercent / 100;
            // Return a gradient based on the value
            return LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
              stops: [
                0.0,
                fillPercent,
                fillPercent,
                1.0
              ], // Adjust stops for smooth transition
              colors: [
                fillColor,
                fillColor,
                Colors.white,
                Colors.white,

                // Background color
              ],
            );
          } catch (e) {
            return null;
          }
        }
        return null; // Return null for non-relevant columns
      }

      TextStyle? getTextStyle() {
        return [
          "Made P %",
          "Job Order No",
        ].contains(e.columnName)
            ? const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              )
            : null;
      }

      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: getColor()),
        alignment: [
          "FPO No",
          "FPO Qty",
          "Total Made Qty",
          "Good Qty",
          "Bad Qty",
          "Trn Qty",
          "Rack Qty",
          "Made P %",
          "Due Made P %"
        ].contains(e.columnName)
            ? Alignment.centerRight
            : Alignment.centerLeft,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(
          e.value.toString(),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: getTextStyle(),
        ),
      );
    }).toList());
  }

  @override
  Widget? buildGroupCaptionCellWidget(
      RowColumnIndex rowColumnIndex, String summaryValue) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 5,
          vertical: 5,
        ),
        child: Text(summaryValue));
  }
}

class JobHistory {
  final String? jobOrderNo;
  final String? fpoNo;
  final String? item;
  final String? creationDate;
  final String? planStartDate;
  final String? planCmplDate;
  final num? fpoQty;
  final num? goodQty;
  final num? badQty;
  final num? trnQty;
  final num? rackQty;
  final double? madeP;
  final double? dueMadeP;
  final String? customerName;
  final String? customerPo;
  final String? buyerName;

  JobHistory({
    this.jobOrderNo,
    this.fpoNo,
    this.item,
    this.creationDate,
    this.planStartDate,
    this.planCmplDate,
    this.fpoQty,
    this.goodQty,
    this.badQty,
    this.trnQty,
    this.rackQty,
    this.madeP,
    this.dueMadeP,
    this.customerName,
    this.customerPo,
    this.buyerName,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMapForTab() {
    return {
      "Job Order No": jobOrderNo,
      "FPO No": fpoNo,
      "Item": item,
      "FPO Qty": fpoQty,
      "Good Qty": goodQty,
      "Bad Qty": badQty,
      "Trn Qty": trnQty,
      "Rack Qty": rackQty,
      "Made P %": "$madeP %",
      "Due Made P %": "$dueMadeP %",
    };
  }
}


I have posted an issue regarding this problem. They told me it is not possible to get row data while it is grouped


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
